# How to parse a specific HTML tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to webscrape this website: https://datausa.io/profile/university/cuny-city-college/

My code only retrieves the first matching div class tag which is tuition but I only want to retrieve Room and Board cost. How do I parse a specific tag?

```
import requests

url = requests.get('https://datausa.io/profile/university/cuny-city-college/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')

rb = soup.find('div',class_='stat-value')

print(rb.prettify)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do use `find` method on `state-titel` and add specific text in it so it will find that tag and we have to extract previous tag from it so use `previous` method on it!

```
import requests

url = requests.get('https://datausa.io/profile/university/cuny-city-college/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')

rb = soup.find('div',class_='stat-title',text="Room and Board").find_previous()
print(rb.get_text())
```

Output:

```
$15,406
```

Comment: Thanks! You're the best

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:has`, `:-soup-contains`, and an adjacent sibling combinator (+), to specify `stat-value` with immediately adjacent `stat-title` containing text "Room and Board"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(requests.get('https://datausa.io/profile/university/cuny-city-college/').text)
print(soup.select_one('.stat-value:has(+ .stat-title:-soup-contains("Room and Board"))').text)
```